# Passing columns dynamically as arguments to a function in pandas with list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe:

```
p     s
ABCD  AB,AC,AD
XY    XY   
MSD   MS,MD
PQRS  PQ,PR,PS
```

I'm using following syntax to split column s into column s0,s1,s2....

```
df = df.join(df['s'].str.split(',', expand=True).add_prefix('s').fillna(np.nan))
```

which wull result in

```
p     s         s0    s1    s2
ABCD  AB,AC,AD  AB    AC    AD 
XY    XY        XY    NaN   NaN
MSD   MS,MD     MS    MD    NaN
PQRS  PQ,PR,PS  PQ    PR    PS
```

Now I want to pass these newly generated column values into a function along with some other column values.
For Eg:

```
def compare(p,s0,s1,s2):
    //piece of code
```

Suppose the number of columns generated(Say one time 13, means s0,s1,s2,...s12 and another time 15, s0,s1,...,s13) varies from dataset to dataset(depends on number of fields present in column s separated by commas). Is there a way so that I can pass these column values dynamically to function on basis of number of columns created?

Something like following:
def compare(p,[list comrehension])

Can I get any suggstions??

Comment: If you want dynamic number of arguments in the function then `**kwargs` is an option.

Comment: You can pack arguments using a "starred" argument.  `def compare(p, *cols):`

Comment: My question is about how to pass large arguments in a function call and not to handle using *args or **kwargs

Comment: I'm already using *args to handle variable arguments in my function... But how can I pass multiple columns(s0,s1,s2,........,s35) as arguments to a function call in pandas

Comment: Is this possible with list comprehension??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Index.difference` method to generate a list of the new columns:

```
new_columns = df.columns.difference(old_columns).tolist()
```

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def compare(p, new_columns):
    print(new_columns)

df = pd.DataFrame({'p': ['ABCD', 'XY', 'MSD', 'PQRS'],
                   's': ['AB,AC,AD', 'XY', 'MS,MD', 'PQ,PR,PS']})

old_columns = df.columns
df = df.join(df['s'].str.split(',', expand=True).add_prefix('s').fillna(np.nan))
new_columns = df.columns.difference(old_columns).tolist()

compare(df['p'], new_columns)
```

prints

```
['s0', 's1', 's2']
```

Comment: Thanks.. I was trying to find the max length of split of column s and then I was trying with list comprehenson [s+str(i) for i in range(max)]. But It was passing string(obviously)...